# How do you reset/clear a d3-brush?

Tags: d3.js

**D3 version 4.2.2**

I have a chart where I want the user to be able to keep zooming in with brush selections. I want to clear or reset my brush within the end event so that the user does not see the old brush.

**Current TypeScript code:**

```
    let brushGroup = this.svg.append('g')
        .attr('class', 'brush');

    let b = brushX()
        .on('start', () => {
            console.log('start brush');
            brushGroup.style('opacity', 100);
        })
        .on('end', () => {
            console.log('end brush', event.selection);
            // remove and display none destroy the brush, so use opacity
            brushGroup.style('opacity', 0);

            this.updateDateRange(this.xScale.invert(event.selection[0]),
                this.xScale.invert(event.selection[1]));
        });

    brushGroup.call(b);
    console.log(brushGroup);
```

- `display: none` prevents future brush start events
- `brushGroup.remove()` also destroys the brush
- opacity works, but the brush is still there (mouse cursor changes on hover)

So what is the correct way to clear or reset the brush?

1. Should I just move it to 0,0?
2. Should I destroy the old brush and create a new one every time?

Comment: I decided to just remove and re-create the brushGroup (g element) within the end event each time. This works well, but I'm still curious if there's a better way.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

selection.call(brush.move, null);

https://github.com/d3/d3-brush/issues/10

Comment: Just to make sure people know what does `selection` and `brush` mean here, `selection` is the brush container (e.g. `svg.append("g").<...>`), and brush is `d3.brush().<...>` chain.